# List tree with groups and elements in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Using any visual component in Cocoa Application, how can I make tree list of groups and elements in them?

Comment: check out this link for help. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tree

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty vague question, but you could start by looking at [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSTreeNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).